# How to show the biggest rectangle in OpenCV Haar classifier

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have already trained positive and negative images on side view of a car using haar cascade object detection, now when i use cascade xml file to predict car in the images i get multiple rectangles.

Now
1)why am i getting multiple rectangle around my object.
2)How to show only the largest rectangle detected in image

**Output Image**

[image]

This is the type of output that i am getting on every image

**Code**

```
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/cascade.xml')
img = cv2.imread('test/46.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)    

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You can filter out the small rectangles by size.

Answer (score 6):

Piglet's answer will help you set a threshold for the minimum / maximum size, but if you wanted to find the largest bounding box in the image, you could do something like this:

```
areas = [w*h for x,y,w,h in cars]
i_biggest = np.argmax(areas)
biggest = cars[i_biggest]
```

Here, we're doing the following:

1. Calculating all bounding box areas using list comprehension
2. Finding the index of `areas` with the largest value, storing in `i_biggest`
3. Using this index to extract the biggest (largest area) rectangle from `cars`

Answer (score 1):

As the function name alread suggests `cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale` and the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) says:

> Detects objects of different sizes in the input image

Also from the documentation:

> Python: cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(image[, scaleFactor[,
>   minNeighbors[, flags[, **minSize**[, maxSize]]]]]) → objects
>
> **minSize** – Minimum possible object size. Objects smaller than that are
>   ignored.

So either you filter the list of resulting rectangles by size or you prevent small objects by setting the minSize parameter.

Comment: Thanks,i have got the largest one ,but every image has different size,so i think i have to do it dynamically.